# "In contemplation of"

Tags: legalese

I came across this phrase in an legal case relating to an ante-nuptial agreement, and was wondering what it meant exactly. The sentence is:

> Agreement concluded prior to and in contemplation of marriage
>   providing that neither party to derive any interest in or benefit from
>   property of other either during marriage or on its termination

Is it synonymous with "in consideration of"/"in expectation of"?

Thanks

Comment: This is very likely jargon, so I doubt any answer is generally applicable. From context, it just looks like "while marriage was being considered." It establishes a time period.

Comment: @Jeremy: It's not that uncommon - OP's specific ["prior to and in contemplation of **marriage**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22prior+to+and+in+contemplation+of+marriage%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) occurs 313 times in Google Books, and there are [far more](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22prior+to+and+in+contemplation+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) if you drop the word "marriage". And it *doesn't* really mean "while marriage was being considered." It means "when it's **fully expected**".

Answer (score 5):

*In contemplation of* means not *in expectation of* but *with specific regard to the possibility of*.

Parties expecting to marry might make or have made in the past agreements of all sorts--for instance, one party may be a vendor to the other party's firm, or they may have entered into a formal business partnership, or both may have been parties to an agreement settling a suit regarding a third party's will. At the time of those agreements they may or may not have expected to marry; but those agreements had no terms which explicitly referred to a marriage between the parties: they did not *contemplate* such a marriage. An ante-nuptial agreement, however, does *contemplate* the marriage of the parties to each other: it is executed with the intention of regulating the marriage they expect to enter into.

EDIT:
I have modified my first line to reflect the holding, in *Cain v. Moon* (1896),  that a valid *donatio mortis causa* or deathbed gift “must have been made **in contemplation, though not necessarily in expectation**, of death.” [emphasis mine] That is, *contemplation* implies that the donor need not **expect** to die shortly, he must merely be considering that he **may** die shortly.

Comment: You could go a bit further, *with specific regard to the **full** expectation of*. I think in such legal contexts, whilst the lawyers have left themselves a possible "get-out" clause in case the marriage *doesn't* take place, they seriously don't expect anything to stop it when they draft things like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  That's doubtless what the parties mean, or they wouldn't go to the trouble and expense of drawing up the agreement; but what the *phrase* means is what the law cares about, that the agreement is directed towards a contingency, not a fact.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  See my edit.

Comment: +1 There's a [helpful WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donatio_mortis_causa#Contemplation_of_death) that you might want to link to.

Comment: Nothing is certain except death and taxes. So I guess if the law allows you to be *not necessarily in expectation of death*, they'd hardly expect you to be particularly sure whether you were going to marry.

Comment: @coleopterist  Yah, that was my jumping-off point.